# Guava Collections - filter by array of String values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, filtering, guava

I have a list of Event ojects. Each object exposes `getId()` getter. I need to filter collection to get only items with specific id, I can do that this way:

```
Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(ret, x->x.getCategoryId().equals(category)));
```

As a result, I'm getting new array, filtered to items, where `getCategoryId()` equals my specific `category`.

Fine so far. Problem: what if instead of single, specific category, I have array of `String` values (all categories to be used as filter). This could look as follows:

```
Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(ret, x->x.getCategoryId().equals(categories.get(0)) || x.getCategoryId().equals(categories.get(1)) || ......../*To the end of the list*/));
```

As my `categories` list is dynamic, I need to use dynamic query to get all `||` criteria applied. What is the best approach to do that? Can I loop it somehow or provide **array** as my criteria to `filter` method?

NOTES: I'm on Android, so:

- Java 8 lambdas can be used (as you can see above) to simplify syntax.
- Java 8 streams can't be used (because min api is Android Lollipop). This is why Guava is used to perform filtering. Please don't propose any soultions based on Java 8 streams.

So, do  you have any idea?

Comment: wait, you can use lambda but still stick to the guava instead of java-8 filtering for example?

Comment: yes, this is Android limitation, otherwise I will be forced to use minApi Nougat (app won't work on older Android versions). As long as I want my app to run on Android older than 7.0, stream api is forbidden (but lambdas, guava is fine)

Comment: Yes, it seems so, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is build a guava `Predicate`, since you would need fast look-up, it might pay off to build a `Set` from that array first:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));
```

And than simply replace the Predicate:

```
x -> set.contains(x.getCategoryId())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only Java 8, you'd do something like:

```
final Set<String> categories = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("category 1", "category 2"));
ret.stream()
   .filter(x -> categories.contains(x.getCategoryId()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: read the question and the comments under it, user *can not* use streams

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed that.